# Modification of array objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to rebuild an array ,so I need suggestion on doing it using best practices.
I have an array object as follows:

```
MainObject:
0:"Namebar"
  1: Object
    Name: "Title1"
    Url: "Url1"
  2: Object
    Name: "Title2"
    Url: "Url2"
  3: Object
    Name: "Title3"
    Url: "Url1"
```

In the above since the "url" is same , I want to group it same object and I am expecting the output in the following format:

```
0: "Url1"
  1: Object
    Name : "Title1"
    Url: "Namebar"
  2: Object
    Name : "Title3"
    Url: "Namebar"

1: "Url2"
  1: Object
    Name : "Title2"
    Url: "Namebar"
```

I am trying to have two arrays and loop through the MainObject for swapping the items which I know is not only a teadious process but very much high on time complexity.
For example like  :

```
var extract1 = MainObject[0];
var extract2 = using for loop to extract and swap ......
```

I am not getting any other way of achieving this. Any approach for this in javascript/jquery?

Comment: what is the property name for `Namebar` in the `MainObject`? And what is the property name of an array in `MainObject`

Comment: @AlexArt.: There is no propertyname for Namebar , just MainObject[0] gives output as "Namebar" , whereas MainObject[1] and 2 are arrays with structures as above

Comment: How do you get nested array?

Comment: show `MainObject` array in it's literal form, not as text.

Comment: var MainObject = new Array();  MainObject.push(name) ;MainObject.push(json object);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
var extract1 = MainObject[0];
var newArray = {};
var newArrProp;
var extract1Props = Object.keys(extract1);
for( i = 0; i< extract1Props.length; i++)
{
   newArrProp = extract1Props[i];
   var nestedObjects = extract1[newArrProp];
   for(j = 0; j < nestedObjects.length; j++)
   {
      if(!newArray[nestedObjects[j].Url])
      {
          newArray[nestedObjects[j].Url] = [];              
      }
      newArray[nestedObjects[j].Url].push({Name:nestedObjects[j].Name,Url:newArrProp});
   }
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqpjehbv/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use some loops.

```js
var MainObject = [{ "Namebar": [{ Name: "Title1", Url: "Url1" }, { Name: "Title2", Url: "Url2" }, { Name: "Title3", Url: "Url1" }] }],
    object2 = [];

MainObject.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        a[k].forEach(function (b) {
            var temp = {};
            if (!this[b.Url]) {
                temp[b.Url] = [];
                this[b.Url] = temp[b.Url];
                object2.push(temp);
            }
            this[b.Url].push({ name: b.Name, Url: k });
        }, this);
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>object2 ' + JSON.stringify(object2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>MainObject ' + JSON.stringify(MainObject, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```